# A question while I was revising the topic of pointers

Tags: c++11, dynamic

Why can only pointers access heap memory in c++ or C ,i.e. what is that the special feature of pointer which allows it to access heap memory?

Comment: Welcome to SO! They store a memory address and the language supports dereferencing them. Is this what you were asking?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about pointers. It's just that the memory for variables is never stored in the heap because they don't need to be there.

- Automatic variables are allocated in activation records on the stack. The compiler converts uses of these variables to offsets from the stack pointer.
- Global variables and static variables are allocated in the data segment (if initialized) or the BSS segment (if default-zero initialization is used). The compiler translates uses of these variables to their addresses in these segments of memory.

The heap is used for data that's allocated dynamically and needs to persist after a function returns. And when this memory is allocated, the location is returned as a pointer, so it must be stored in a pointer variable.

**Note** Nothing in the language specification refers to these memory areas, it just describes abstract semantics. But the question and this answer refer to typical implementations.

There's nothing technically stopping implementations from using the heap to store global and/or static variables. At program startup it could request heap allocations for each global variable, or all of them as a block; and when entering a function with a static variable the first time, it could allocate memory for the variable. But the pointer(s) to these allocations would have to be stored at some known location(s). And it would make access to the variables slower, since they would all have to indirect through these pointers. So it's more efficient to assign these addresses at compile time.

Similarly, activation records could be allocated dynamically in the heap. But heap allocation and deallocation is more expensive than simply adding to a stack pointer register. Furthermore, there's a chicken-and-egg problem: if function calling required dynamic allocation, how would you call the dynamic allocation function? This problem could be solved by having dynamic allocation be built into the implementation using a mechanism other than the normal function calling method, but since there's no reason to do this in the first place, this level of complexity isn't warranted.

Some programming languages have [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) that allow bindings of local variables to persist even after the function returns. Implementations of these languages will use their heap to store these activation records, possibly only doing it dynamically when the closure is created. But C++ doesn't have these types of functions; if you return a function and it tries to access a variable outside the scope that was returned from, it's undefined behavior. Modulo implementations that add this as an extension, C++ allows all automatic variables to be stored in the stack, and this is the most efficient way to do it.